# how to give few access controls to user after login

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

Shiro plugin giving access to user for particular actions.

https://grails.org/plugin/shiro

I am working on a `grails` application for the first time and I now want to protect some pages to be viewed only by admins, and give some permissions to other users.

Comment: Provide more details about the question.

Comment: The user has to log in while the admin is okay,  @Ashu

Answer (score 0):

As this reference page(https://grails.org/plugin/shiro) suggests :

You will need to define roles and their permission

```
 def adminRole = new ShiroRole(name: "Administrator")
 adminRole.addToPermissions("printer:*:*")
 adminRole.addToPermissions("admin")
 …
 adminRole.save()
```

Now suppose you want to add few pages URL to `admin` role. 
You can call addToPermissions for that, in above code `"printer:*:*"` means that all the resources under `printer` will be accessible to `admin` profile.

You can create multiple roles with different permissions and attach them to different user which will help you to segregate the pages for different roles.